# How do I get SVN version from SharpSVN?

Tags: c#, winforms, svn

The question is simple.  I've using SharpSVN in a C# WinForms application.  My users have problems when the version of SVN is below 1.8.  How can I determine the version of SVN they're using so I can give them a warning that the application won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All recent Subversion minor releases included a new version of the working copy format. So your application's SharpSvn version should match the working copy of the users' other Subversion clients.

If you just want your users Working copy to upgrade to your version of the library you can use SvnClient.Upgrade() to upgrade existing working copies.

But once you upgraded a working copy of a user, their other Subversion clients (based on older versions) won't be able to read the working copy until they are also upgraded.

Comment: Right, but is there a sort of `SvnClient.IsAnOldWorkingCopy(string path)` that we can call first so we know that `SvnClient.Upgrade()` will succeed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look in:
[sharpsvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/)